# Scanner asks for input twice and im slowly loosing my mind

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i am trying to get two inputs from the scanner (multiple times if needed).
The code in Question is in the else section of the main function but i decided to share everything since something may collide, i don't know. the problem is that the first scanner(the timed one) works fine but the other two scanners (scanner1) require me to first press enter once then input the data and press enter again. Also if it has something to do with having two scanners then i would like for scanner1 not to be timed. Its not tragic but a flaw and i would like to fix it. Can somebody help me because i am running out of ideas.

Sorry if i made spelling mistakes or if my gramar sucks.

````
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimedScanner implements Runnable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TimedScanner scanner = new TimedScanner();
        System.out.print("Enter the number of searchagents you want to add in 15 second: ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine(15000);
        if (input == null)
        {
            System.out.println("\nNothing was entered. Continuing...");
        }
        else
        {
            Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            File myFile = new File("searchagent_list.txt");
            if (!(myFile.exists())) {
                myFile.createNewFile();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                System.out.println("Press Enter!\nEnter the name of searchagent #"+(i+1));
                String name = scanner1.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Press Enter!\nEnter the adress of searchagent #"+(i+1));
                String adress = scanner1.nextLine();
                FileWriter fWrite = new FileWriter(myFile, true);
                BufferedWriter bWrite = new BufferedWriter(fWrite);
                bWrite.write(name+"##"+adress+"##\n");
                bWrite.close();

            }
            System.out.println("Done");

        }
    }

    private Scanner scanner;
    private StringBuilder buffer;
    private boolean reading;
    private Thread t;

    public TimedScanner()
    {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        buffer = new StringBuilder();
        reading = false;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    public String nextLine(long time)
    {
        reading = true;
        String result = null;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < time && result == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
            synchronized (buffer)
            {
                if (buffer.length() > 0)
                {
                    Scanner temp = new Scanner(buffer.toString());
                    result = temp.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
        reading = false;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            synchronized (buffer)
            {
                if (reading)
                {

                    buffer.append(line);
                    buffer.append("\n");

                }
                else
                {
                    // flush the buffer
                    if (buffer.length() != 0)
                    {
                        buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` after reading will solve your issue:

```java
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            synchronized (buffer) {
                if (reading) {

                    buffer.append(line);
                    buffer.append("\n");

                    return;
                } else {
                    // flush the buffer
                    if (buffer.length() != 0) {
                        buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but there is no benefit to create more than one `Scanner` reference. It's simply reading input from `System.in` stream.